# Carga de CSV erronea

Tags: php, mysqli, csv, importación

En este código tengo un pequeño ejemplo de como cargar CSV:

```
    $message = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$allowed = array('csv');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    // show error message
    $message = 'Archivo invalido, porfavor usa un archivo .CSV!';
} else {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $file = "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE proyectos
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (oferta_proyecto,acro_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion,compania)
eof;
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $message = "CSV importado correctamente!";
}
 }
```

Pero como se ve este solo carga desde un sitio especifico, y lo que quiero es quitarselo, para que los usuarios carguen desde cualquier parte:

Este es el código nuevo que intente

$message = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $allowed = array('csv');
    $filename = $_FILES['name'];

```
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    // show error message
    $message = 'Archivo invalido, porfavor usa un archivo .CSV!';
} else {



    $query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
     INTO TABLE proyectos
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (oferta_proyecto,acro_proyecto,nombre_proyecto,descripcion,compania)
eof;
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $message = "CSV importado correctamente!";
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con carga desde un sitio especifico?

Comment: Por que ahora mismo solo deja cargar csv desde donde esta el sitio web alojado en una carpeta llamada files, y lo que quiero es que cada uno cargue desde su pc desde donde el quiera y que no tenga que acceder al servidor

Comment: El primer trozo de codigo no deberia cargar nada pues $file no esta definida mientras que el segundo si deberia hacertelo. ¿Que error exactamente da?

Comment: Estaba mal ordenado, ahora si, el primer trozo de código es el que funciona pero unicamente desde el servidor, y el segundo es el que quiero modificar para que cargue desde cualquier sitio un CSV

Comment: El nuevo codigo de arriba basicamente recoje un fichero enviado por un usuario desde cualquier sitio mediante un formulario, lo mueve a una ruta concreta y luego lo carga. ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Que no en realidad no carga, como en esa ruta encocreta ya existe un archivo

Comment: ¿Como que ya existe un archivo?

Comment: Vale, eran los permisos en el servidor Centos 7 que el admin no dio permisos de escritura y lectura. Una vez han sido dado sya funciona correctamente.
Para borrar los CSV cada vez que se ejecute el fichero valdria de esta forma:
unlink('*.csv');